# how to add 2 controls to one corner in fabric.js?

Tags: fabricjs

How can I add 2 controls to one corner in fabric.js, one for scaling and another one for rotating the object.

[image]

Comment: I have updated your question to be a bit more readable.

Comment: There is no functionality in fabricjs as such. You need to implement this by your own.

Comment: I have achieved this, if you still need answer then let me know.